# Javascript variable doesn’t work with addeventlistener?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a variable inside javascript, but I receive an `Uncaught TypeError` for the following line: `infoButton.addEventListener('mousedown', buttonDown, false);`.
When I delete the above line, I will receive the error, but not now.

I call loadScript on the body: `<body onload="loadScript()">`.

JS:

```
function loadScript() {
    onDeviceReady();
};

// When device is ready (event listeners)
function onDeviceReady() {

    // Button variable
    var infoButton = document.getElementsByClassName('info');

    // Pages
    var introPage = document.getElementById('introduction');

    // Button events
    // Button info
    infoButton.addEventListener('mousedown', pageInfoShow, false);

    alert(infoButton);

};


// Page functions
function pageInfoShow() { 
    introPage.className = "";
};
```

What do I wrong? Can't I use a variable with an addEventListener?

Comment: Um...`buttonDown` isn't defined by anything in your code before you try to use it.

Comment: Where is buttonDown function ?

Comment: Also note that function *declarations* don't need a `;` at the end, only statements using function expressions. E.g.: `function decl() { }` and `var expr = function() { };`

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByClassName` includes the word "elements", which is a plural. It returns a NodeList (which is like an array) not an element.

You need to call `addEventListener` on each value in the NodeList, not upon the NodeList itself (where it isn't defined).

Comment: How can I select only one element with a class?

Comment: If you mean you have only element that matches, then the same way you would do it with many elements that match. Loop over the very short NodeList and do something to every single item in it. If you want to distinguish between multiple elements that are members of the same class, then you'll need to apply some other test to them.